# Data structure search complexity

Tags: search, stack, queue, time-complexity

Complexity for search in a linked list is O(n).

It is also O(n) for search in an queue or stack, is that right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are unordered then yes, it's `O(n)` since in the worst case you have to examine every element.

Comment: Even if they are ordered, the traversal across a queue will net you O(n) because of no indexed retrival operation over a queue or stack.

Comment: BTW, you quite often do not even have a "search" operation for a stack (you can only access the top directly), or a queue (you can only access the head directly).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.

That depends on your implementation. For example, If you have a hash table inside the queue/stack, you get an "super" queue/stack with O(1) push/pop/search.